# How to create constraint 'EXCLUDE' or 'Unique' with column group and predicate in Postresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints

I have the table:

```
create table mytable (
   id bigint not null primary key,
   org int,
   post int,
   op int,
   staff boolean
)
```

and i need create two constrains:

- unique `org` and `post` if staff is **true**
- unique `org`, `post` and `op` if staff is **false**

But `UNIQUE` contraint doesn't have predicate (clause `where`). I want to use `EXCLUDE` constraint as has clause where, but `EXCLUDE` doesn't support column group in the same operator. I.e :

```
 constraint stafUnique EXCLUDE ( (org,post) with in) where (staff = true)
```

gives an error.

How to implement it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `create unique index` in lieu of [constraint](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/144/when-should-i-use-a-unique-constraint-instead-of-a-unique-index/147#147)

```
create unique index ix_staff_true on mytable(org, post) where staff;

create unique index ix_staff_false on mytable(org, post, op) where not staff;
```